# Meaning of ((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s in Effective java example

Tags: java

I was going through 'equal' method concept in effective java, and there I found below code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof CaseInsensitiveString)
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase(((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s);
    if (o instanceof String)  // One-way interoperability!            
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase((String) o);
    return false;
}
```

Here I am not able to get particular line that is `((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s` . Now what I understand from this piece of code is object 'o' is been typecast to `CaseInsensitiveString` Class. Now what does `).s` mean.

Comment: Don't format large pieces of code with backticks. Indent by four spaces instead. I fixed that, but you should try to fix the other formatting problems as well.

Comment: It's called `casting`

Comment: The `s` is just some type specific field of that particular class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `CaseInsensitiveString` has a member `s` of type `String`.

To access that member, you need to

- cast the `Object o` to `CaseInsensitiveString` using `((CaseInsensitiveString) o)`
- then access the field `s` using `((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't read the `).s` in isolation:

```
return s.equalsIgnoreCase(((CaseInsensitiveString) o).s);
```

Is like:

```
CaseInsensitiveString c = (CaseInsensitiveString) o;
return s.equalsIgnoreCase(c.s);
```

It's just accessing a field from the instance of `CastInsensitiveString`.

Comment: And OP's confusion about what `.s` means is a great example of why you never have public members with names like `s`. If it were a more meaningful name, it might have been more obvious.